# how to display Exam Hall Seat Number in gridview cell as top-left corner and register number in center of cell in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to bind student register number as in DataTable1 in Gridview1 with positions as in DataTable2 .
I want to display Exam Hall seat position number in left top corner of Gridview1 cell and register number in Gridview1 Cell. . I give my .net code , DB table structure and expected Gridview1 display below. If anybody give me solution, I will thankful to you.

**

### C#.Net Code

**

private void dgvHallSeating()
        {

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt;

        DataTable dtSeatPositionsAssign = new DataTable();

        DataColumn col1;
        DataColumn col2;
        DataColumn col3;
        DataColumn col4;
        DataColumn col5;

        dt = new DataTable();
        col1 = new DataColumn("col1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col2 = new DataColumn("col2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col3 = new DataColumn("col3", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col4 = new DataColumn("col4", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        col5 = new DataColumn("col5", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col1);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col2);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col3);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col4);
        dtSeatPositionsAssign.Columns.Add(col5);

        Int32 SeatPositionColIndex = 0;
        Int32 SeatPositionRowIndex = 0;

        DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable2 = CMSBL.dtecSeatSlot1Positions();

        DataTable DataTable1 = CMSBL.rptecSeatSlot1Reports();

        int RegNoRowIndex = 0;
        int HallSeatPosition = 0;

        for (; RegNoRowIndex < 11; RegNoRowIndex++)
        {
            for (; HallSeatPosition < DataTable2.Rows.Count; )
            {
                SeatPositionColIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable2.Rows[HallSeatPosition]["ecGridColumnIndex"]);
                SeatPositionColIndex = SeatPositionColIndex - 1;

                SeatPositionRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(DataTable2.Rows[HallSeatPosition]["ecGridRowIndex"]);
                SeatPositionRowIndex = SeatPositionRowIndex - 1;

                dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Add();
                if (SeatPositionRowIndex >= dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Count || GridView1.Rows.Count <= 5)
                {
                    dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows.Add();
                }
                dtSeatPositionsAssign.Rows[SeatPositionRowIndex][SeatPositionColIndex] =ecHallSeatNo + "  " + DataTable1.Rows[RegNoRowIndex][3].ToString();

                break;
            }
            HallSeatPosition++;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dtSeatPositionsAssign;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

**

### DataTable1

**

[image]

**

### DataTable2

**

[image]

**

### Expected Gridview1 Display

**

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: What a template of your cell? How you bind data to your cell?

Comment: Have you tried using a ListView instead? You can play around with the look and feel of each item instead of using a tabular layout.

Comment: no.. can i display for more than 10 halls and more than 200 register numbers using list view? if means please give sample code how it should be.. it will help me lot.. thanks..